# WDS Not Offering Capture Image

Tags: windows, wds

I have installed WDS and added boot and capture images.

I have a server I am trying to capture, however when I do the network boot, I can see WDS and it loads the boot.wim file instead of the capture.wim.[Images in WDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhNPY.jpg)

I was expecting to see a screen such as this: [Boot Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ur3U.jpg) but I don't and it boots straight into the first image.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now. It appears as if the .wim file may have become slightly corrupted.

I used DISM to mount then unmount the file and can now boot into it.